# How easy is it to return to stock after rooting with Unrevoked?

Tags: unrooting, unrevoked

I have found the following link for rooting several Android devices:

[link text](http://unrevoked.com/rootwiki/doku.php/public/unrevoked2)

It seems quite easy to root, but how difficult is it to go back to unrooted once you've rooted?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a HTC Hero and when I had to unroot my phone, I found the RUU for my phone. This in simple terms is a restore to your phone which the service provider uses to restore the phone to absolute stock. I'd check and see if you couldn't find the RUU to your specific phone!

Good luck!